# cakephp, save multiple row of the same model

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I'm tying to figure out how to save, for example 4 days of schedule in one view, and have each field validation message show if validation fails.

My approach was at first to use `$this->SomeModel->saveAll()` but couldn't save so I tried another way using `foreach` and all data is saved (pass validation) but no validation message is shown. if you guys know better way to do this I'm open for any suggestions.

Model

```
public $validate = array(
    'hour_from'=>array(
        'some mgs' => array(
            'rule'    => 'good_hours',
        ),
    ),
);
public function good_hours($data) {
    //throw new Exception(($data['hour_from'] >= $this->data['Hour']['hour_to']));
    if ($data['hour_from'] >= $this->data['Hour']['hour_to']) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Controller:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $all_good = true;
        foreach ($this->request->data['Hour'] as $day){

            if ($this->Hour->save($day)){

            }else {
                $all_good = false;
                $this->Session->setFlash('hours not saved');
            }
        }
        //if all saves are correct rediredt to index 
        if ($all_good) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Hours saved'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
```

View

```
    foreach ($days as $count => $day):
$form_model ='Hour.'.$count. '.';
?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php
    $day_array = (array) $day;
    $day = $day_array['date'];
    echo $day;
    ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input($form_model.'type_holiday_id', array(
    'label'=> 'Typ urlopu',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => $type_holidays,
    'empty'   => true
    ));
    echo $this->Form->input($form_model.'hour_from', array('label' => 'od'));
    echo $this->Form->input($form_model.'hour_to', array('label' => 'do'));
    echo $this->Form->input($form_model.'date', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $day));
    echo $this->Form->input($form_model.'subordinate_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $user['User']['id']));
    echo $this->Form->input($form_model.'supervisor_id', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $current_user['id']));

?>
</fieldset>
```

Request->data array

```
Hour(array)
0(array)
   type_holiday_id
   hour_from 8
   hour_to 15
   date 2014-01-20
   subordinate_id 193
   supervisor_id 557
1(array)
   type_holiday_id
   hour_from 7
   hour_to 14
   date 2014-01-21
   subordinate_id 193
   supervisor_id 557
```

Comment: I think the saveAll() method would be your best bet here -- multiple rows of the same model is the use case for this method.  What does the `$day` array look like?  I bet your issue is in the format of the array.  As for validation display on the view, you might have to call it directly.  I seem to recall having a similar issue in the past which I ended up using the validate() method to return data to the view when it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found solution, and everything works perfectly now in controller i needed to change `save` to `saveAll`,  function `add` in Controller should look like this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Hour->saveAll($this->request->data['Hour'], Array('validate' => 'first', 'deep' => true))){ <--- most important is that data['Hour']
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Godziny robocze zapisane')); 
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else{
            $this->Session->setFlash('Godziny robocze nie zostały zapisane.');
        }
    }
```